# How to do case insensitive filtering in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just started working on MongoDB and below is my code.  I need to ignore casing while filtering data how to do it?

```
db.collection.aggregate([

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "el",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$el",
              [
                "Min", //need to ignore casing
                "max",
                "gg"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just a quick solution... adding both `min` and `Min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) operator to convert the filter element to lowercase then ensure the array elements in the conditional expression are all in lowercase:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "el",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              // Convert the input element to lower case
              { "$toLower": "$$el" },
              // Ensue all the elements of the array below are in lower case
              [
                "min",
                "max",
                "gg"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```